# Whats the best way to add an SVG to ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a component that displays an SVG in React. I am not having any luck, does anyone know a good practice for turns SVG's into React components.

I tried adding them to <img /> tags and <svg /> tags but i keep getting a broken image icon?

Comment: Please provide more info, like the code you've tried to run. Also, check the browser console as it usually provides info about any issues regarding trying to load resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best practice that I have found is that save `svg` in simple SVG tag and import it like this in your project

`import { ReactComponent as EmptyWallet } from 'src/assets/svgs/EmptyWallet.svg';`

EmptyWallet.svg file will look like this

```
<svg>
<path d="M29.73,17.66H0V47.79H29.73V59.28c.21,5,3.88,6.78,8.42,5.25a2.47,2.47,0,0,0,.7-.37c11.47-9,19.37-18,30.84-27l.16-.13c3.49-3.18,2.46-6.8-.93-9.47L40.81,2.61A13.25,13.25,0,0,0,36.65.28C34-.51,31.54.37,30.41,3a10,10,0,0,0-.68,3.93c0,3.57-.05,7.16,0,10.73ZM93.15,64h29.73V94.16H93.15v11.48c-.21,5-3.88,6.79-8.42,5.25a2.24,2.24,0,0,1-.7-.37c-11.47-9-19.37-18-30.84-27L53,83.38c-3.49-3.17-2.46-6.8.93-9.46L82.07,49a13,13,0,0,1,4.16-2.32c2.66-.8,5.11.08,6.24,2.71a10,10,0,0,1,.68,3.94c0,3.56.06,7.16,0,10.72Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function SVG() {
 return (
    <svg
      id="Layer_1"
    >
      <path d="M29.73,17.66H0V47.79H29.73V59.28c.21,5,3.88,6.78,8.42,5.25a2.47,2.47,0,0,0,.7-.37c11.47-9,19.37-18,30.84-27l.16-.13c3.49-3.18,2.46-6.8-.93-9.47L40.81,2.61A13.25,13.25,0,0,0,36.65.28C34-.51,31.54.37,30.41,3a10,10,0,0,0-.68,3.93c0,3.57-.05,7.16,0,10.73ZM93.15,64h29.73V94.16H93.15v11.48c-.21,5-3.88,6.79-8.42,5.25a2.24,2.24,0,0,1-.7-.37c-11.47-9-19.37-18-30.84-27L53,83.38c-3.49-3.17-2.46-6.8.93-9.46L82.07,49a13,13,0,0,1,4.16-2.32c2.66-.8,5.11.08,6.24,2.71a10,10,0,0,1,.68,3.94c0,3.56.06,7.16,0,10.72Z" />
    </svg>
  );
}

SVG.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: oh wow, i was so close, thank you Justin you nailed it.

Comment: `value` doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: true its just an extra param i forgot to remove sorry

Comment: it's removed from the svg

Answer (score 0):

this is another that i got work but I like yours a lot better thank Justin.

```
 import mySvg from './path/to/image.svg';
 export default function Svg() { 
     return (<img src="/path/to/image.svg" alt="SVG as an image">)
 }
```